# Is there a closed-form for $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left|X_1X_2\right|}{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_d^2}\right]$, where all the $X_i$ are normal i.i.d.?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, closed-form

I would like to compute $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left|X_1X_2\right|}{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_d^2}\right]$$
where all the $X_i$ ae i.i.d. according to a standard normal Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

It's easy to get an upper-bound on this quantity via:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left|X_1X_2\right|}{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_d^2}\right]\leqslant\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left|X_1X_2\right|}{X_3^2+\cdots+X_d^2}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_1\right|\right]^2\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X_3^2+\cdots+X_d^2}\right]=\frac{2}{\pi(d-4)}$$

This upper-bound works well for large $d$, which is what I'm interested in anyway, but I was curious if it was possible to get a closed-form for this expression. Neither computing directly the integral nor somehow breaking down the expression into independent smaller ones seems possible. In fact, I'm not even sure this has a closed form to begin with. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Is it really an upper bound?? What happens If $d = 3$. The Expectation is surely positive right?

Comment: Have you tried using spherical coordinates on $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(x_3,...,x_n)$ respectivelly? Or just $(x_1,x_2)$ and use the fact that $(X_1,X_2)$ and $X_3^2+...+X_n^2$ are independent, where the latter is distributed as Gamma random variable with parameters $\frac{n-3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ (in one of its versions).

Comment: @Gregory I think this works for $d\geqslant5$, because $\frac{1}{X_3^2}$ and $\frac{1}{X_3^2+X_4^2}$ don't have finite expected value (unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: @DominikKutek I'm not sure I understand your second point. The law of $X_3^2+\cdots+X_d^2$ is known (it's a $\chi^2(d-2)$), but computing $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2+z}f(x)f(y)g(z)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$ seems tedious. How would you go from there to spherical coordinates? Write $(x, y)$ as $(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))$?

Comment: Yes, I'd definitelly try so. Maybe even with substituting $z=w^2$ then, in order to have $r^2 + w^2$ in the denominator which gives an opportunity for another polar coordinates? Just loose thoughts.

Comment: Maybe simpler: conditional on its norm, a Gaussian vector is uniform over the sphere. But notice that the expression is invariant to scaling anyway, so this means that the answer should be the same as $\mathbb{E}[|X_1X_2|]$ where $X$ is drawn uniformly over the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks! I'll try.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I totally agree, but I have the feeling that we'll end up with basically the same integral at the end, since on the $n$-sphere $X_1$ and $X_2$ aren't independant anymore. I'll give it a try though, thanks!

Comment: Actually no, see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $X = RY,$  where $R = \|X\|$ and $Y$ is uniform over the unit sphere. We'll use the standard fact that $R$ and $Y$ are independent.

First observe that expressing things in polar coordinate, the expression we're looking for is just $\mathbb{E}[|Y_1Y_2|]$. But since $R$ and $Y$ are independent, we have $$ 2/\pi  = \mathbb{E}[|X_1X_2|] = \mathbb{E}[R^2|Y_1Y_2|] = \mathbb{E}[R^2]\mathbb{E}[|Y_1Y_2|],$$ where I've also used the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Finally, $$\mathbb{E}[R^2] = \mathbb{E}[\sum X_i^2] = d.$$ So we get that $\mathbb{E}[|Y_1Y_2|] = 2/(\pi d)$.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$(U_1,U_2)=\left(\frac{X_1^2}{X_1^2+\cdots,X_n^2},\frac{X_2^2}{X_1^2+\cdots,X_n^2}\right)$ has the Dirichlet density
$$u_1^{-1/2}u_2^{-1/2}(1-u_1-u_2)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-1)}$$ and you are asking for
$$E(\sqrt{U_1U_2})=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-1)}\times \int_{u_1+u_2<1}(1-u_1-u_2)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}du_1du_2=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-1)}\times \frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)} =\frac{2}{n\pi}.$$

Comment: I was wondering whether there was an analytical way. Thanks!